# How to refer in an acknowledgements section to a group of people in industry who helped you in completing your thesis?

Tags: thesis, industry, acknowledgement

My thesis was done in industry environment, therefore in the acknowledgements I would like to thank all the people that helped me, but I do not know how I should call  them. Colleagues does not sound right to me since I am not actually employed in that company although I spend there every day of the last 5 months.

Which is the right english word? (I am a non native english speaker, but I have to write my thesis in english). Moreover, which is the right word for my industry tutor? Shall I call it advisor (whereas my professor will be my supervisor)? Or is it better to say co-supervisor?

And lastly...shall I write both their name and surname or only the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is similar to but slightly different from [jakebeal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/22733/jakebeal), but gives more meaningful context about this company's contribution and *why* you are thankful to them.

> I am indebted to [COMPANY] and their managers and employees for serving as host and advisers to me for five months as I performed the core of my research.  In particular, I would like to thank [NAME], who graciously tutored me about [TOPICS] which enabled me to [CONTRIBUTION].  I would also like to thank [NAME], [NAME], AND [NAME], who provided feedback and guidance along the way.

You should list first and last names for each person, including titles if they have a PhD or are a medical doctor: "John Jones, PhD" or "Dr. John Jones".

Answer (score 3):

You can largely avoid the terminology question by saying something like:

> Thank you to my company supervisor [NAME] and to the people at [COMPANY] who I have worked with, including [NAMES]